# Error: 'Toast' is imported from both 'package:easy_alert/src/provider.dart' and 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart'

Tags: dart, flutter

```
Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:77:32: Error: 'Toast' is imported from both
'package:easy_alert/src/provider.dart' and 
'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart'.
toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

If I want to use 'Toast' in easy_alert, how to do it?
And if I want to use 'Toast' in fluttertoast, how to do it?

Attention: both package may exist in the project.

Comment: use `import 'xxxx' as yyy;` form and then `yyy.Toast` - more [here](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/get-started#importing-libraries-from-packages)

Comment: @pskink I have seen most of the solutions you provide are just limited to comments, I would recommend you to write them as answer so that you reputation increases too. Like this comment is indeed a good candidate for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that the Object `Toast` that you're importing exists on both packages imported on the class. To solve this issue, you can name the imported package similar to what have been mentioned in the comments. Doing so will give the packages a unique id.

```dart
import 'package:easy_alert/src/provider.dart' as provider;
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart' as ftoast;
```

Then you can call the `Toast` object from either packages by using the assigned names.

As a sample

```dart
provider.Toast();
ftoast.Toast();
```